# Captcha-like font

Tags: typography

I'm looking for a font that reminds of a captcha without being too difficult to read. It has to be available from google web fonts though.

Does anyone have any good tips?

**Edit:** It doesn't have to have a real captcha functionality. I'm making a game where a font like this would fit very well.

So basically, a font that reminds the user of a captcha, without being exhaustive to read over long periods. And available on google-fonts.

Comment: you can use normal font (but not too normal :), make the letter distance less than 0, but greater than half the width (otherwise will over-overlap), and highlight(or whiten) the overlap area. Very difficult for program to analysis.

Comment: plus.. move letter up/down randomly

Comment: The captcha function is not really what I'm after, I just want to recreate the look of a captcha in the most simple way, the readers are going to be humans anyway and its not to test them really.

Comment: they why you need a captcha, to scare robots away? Use font like `Cooper`, `Chiller`, easy to find. Or use `Giddyup Std` but may need license fee. Or `new facebook` font. Email me if you need the font file eric#ericyin[dot]com

Comment: never said I wanted a captcha, I want a font reminding of a captcha. Big difference. :) I'll check out those fonts.

Comment: Strangest reguest I've seen in a good while because people lloooove captcha texts.

Comment: @Lollero That's kind of the point, the theme of the game is hating captcha's.

Comment: @hustlerinc Ah, Roger that.

Comment: @Eric are you advertising to send fonts to people? I'd recommend you not do that.

Comment: @DA01, OP is people but people is not OP. I only offer help to OP and I know what is free font and what is not. To answer your question, I did not "advertising" to send fonts to "people"

Comment: Neither Giddyup nor Cooper are 'free' fonts (though I'm sure bad or illegal knock-offs exist). It's fine to share fonts with licenses that allow that. Just be sure the license allows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "captcha-like", since there are plenty of different looking CAPTCHAs out there.  If you want something like the barely readable scanned text from [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha), you could try some "old typewriter" fonts, like [Mom's Typewriter](http://users.cuci.nl/nonsuch/free.htm) by Christoph Mueller, which I found [here on fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/MomsTypewriter) by Googling for "rough typewriter font":

> [image: SAMPLE TEXT]

Of course, you could also just find some crappy scanned old documents and make your own font in [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) — after all, it's not like the result needs to be of particularly high quality.

Comment: Yeah that typewriter would do the trick, if I mix upper and lower case and placing the letters a little random. Thx.

Comment: Thought I should update and tell u the font worked perfect. Thx for the help.

Comment: The thing about reCaptcha is: the images are scans from old books where the OCR could not read them. With reCaptcha it presents one which it knows and one it doesn't and rates your success on the one it doesn't know against your success on the one it knows. Anyway, if you want a font like on recapthca, open an old book.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is 9 years old, but the closest I have found in my similar search is [ZXX.](https://walkerart.org/magazine/sang-mun-defiant-typeface-nsa-privacy) an anti OCR font.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Captcha Like font + Only from Google Web fonts = no such thing.

A font like that has incredibly limited usefulness, and even though Google fonts has some odd choices in its collection, I don't see why they'd have any interest in adding a novelty font such as that to the collection.

Comment: ..Of course there is Captcha-Like font there, exactly in which "Mom's Typewriter" has been written above. And I don't think Google Fonts will not want to keep a font like this when it has other odd ones! This is one of the various styles and one needs it at times.